# Formatting different parts of the address

Tags: c#

What is a nice way of generating a line of string that shows the address?
Lets say I have the parts of address such as `Zip, State, Line1, Line2` in different variables.
And I want to generate something like

```
Line1, Line2, City, State, Zip
```

Note that some of the field may be missing.

Well easy and butt ugly solution is to check to see if those values are not empty and decided wether to add the "," between them or not but like I said I was hoping for a "nicer" way? A parser or string formatter maybe ?

Comment: One possible solution could be to put your values into a string array and then Join() them.

Comment: @Filburt : Thanks, can you please explain more.

Comment: Konrad Kokosa has the exact answer for that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create a temporary array of those values and use `string.Join` for only valid elements:

```
var str = string.Join(", ", new string[] { Line1, Line2, City, State, Zip }
                                .Where(s => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s)));
```

Comment: This looks like the cleanest solution;

Answer (score 1):

The following should do it.

```
String s = String.Format(" {0}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {4}", Line1, Line2, City, State, Zip).Replace(" ,", String.Empty);
if (s.EndsWith(",")) {
  s=s.SubString(0,s.Length-1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want your string to be more readable (e.g. if you log it), I would suggest to indicate that data is not available rather than skip it. Also, you can wrap it in a class to make it more maintainable.

```
public class Address
{
    private const string UnknownMessage = "Unknown";
    private const string AddressStringFormat = 
       "Addres Line 1: {0}, Address Line 2: {1}, City: {2}, State: {3}, Zip: {4}";

    public string AddressLine1 { get; set; }
    public string AddressLine2 { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string Zip { get; set; }

    public Address(string addressLine1, string addressLine2, string city, string state, string zip)
    {
        this.AddressLine1 = addressLine1;
        this.AddressLine2 = addressLine2;
        this.City = city;
        this.State = state;
        this.Zip = zip;
    }

    public string GetStringRepresentation()
    {
        return String.Format(AddressStringFormat, 
            String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(AddressLine1) ? UnknownMessage : AddressLine1,
            String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(AddressLine2) ? UnknownMessage : AddressLine2,
            String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(City) ? UnknownMessage : City,
            String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(State) ? UnknownMessage : State,
            String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Zip) ? UnknownMessage : Zip);
    }
}
```

Comment: How does this solution remove the commas from the output when the referenced address part isn't there?

Comment: @ChrisLively It does not. My assumption is that if you return a string with info, then you want this string to be representative. IMHO adding `UnknownMessage` is more expressive and consistent than skipping a field. Updated the answer to indicate that it doesn't answer the question directly, but rather suggest another approach.

Comment: Although I understand your position, the reality is that for emitting addresses you generally only want the parts you actually have.  Adding "unknown" will simply result in a screen shot of your output being posted to thedailywtf.com; or, potentially, having a very mad boss when you've printed 5000 envelopes with that on it.

Comment: @ChrisLively Agreed. You don't want to show this string to your users. I thought more about logging. However, skipping missing data is not the best way to present information to users too I suppose. In this case you can change implementation of `GetStringRepresentation` to something fancy (e.g. get missing data from some API).